# Custom Object multiple lines

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject

I created a script to pull some info from AD, the problem I'm having is the Secondary SMTP address field has more then one line.  I'd like to show each secondary SMTP in a new line.  My Script output looks like `{smtp:joe.rodriguez@con...`

```
$searchBase = 'OU=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=LOCAL'

$users = Get-ADUser -filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase $searchBase |select -expand samaccountname

Foreach ($user in $users){ 
$Secondary = get-recipient -Identity $user -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| select Name -ExpandProperty emailaddresses |? {$_.Prefix -like "SMTP" -and $_.IsPrimaryAddress -like "False"} |select -ExpandProperty $_.Smtpaddress 

New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
Name = Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties DisplayName |select  -ExpandProperty DisplayName
"Login ID" = Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties SamAccountName |select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
Primary = get-recipient -Identity $user -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| select Name -ExpandProperty emailaddresses |? {$_.Prefix -like "SMTP" -and $_.IsPrimaryAddress -like "True"} |select -ExpandProperty Smtpaddress 
Secondary =  $Secondary 
  }
}
```

Comment: When you populate `$Secondary`, I think you want to use `select -ExpandProperty smtpaddress` instead of `$_.smtpaddress` to get the secondary email address(es).

Comment: That then shows `{joe.rodriguez@contoso.com...` there list is still not expanded

Comment: No, but beforehand `$Secondary` was being populated with all selected properties (Name, ProxyAddressString, etc.) rather than just the email address(es). It's a step in the right direction.

Comment: The default display formatting won't put those addresses on separate lines.  You'll have to write a script or function to display them that way, or create a custom object type and define a custom display format in types.ps1xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd make an array, pull your user list, and then iterate through the secondary SMTP addresses for each user adding your custom object to the array for each entry.

```
$Userlist = @()

$searchBase = 'OU=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=LOCAL'
$users = Get-ADUser -filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase $searchBase -Properties DisplayName

Foreach ($user in $users){ 
    $Recip = get-recipient -Identity $user.samaccountname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| select Name -ExpandProperty emailaddresses |? {$_.Prefix -like "SMTP"}

    $Recip|? {$_.IsPrimaryAddress -like "False"} |select -ExpandProperty Smtpaddress |%{
        $UserList += New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
            Name = $User.DisplayName
            "Login ID" = $User.SamAccountName
            Primary = $Recip|? {$_.IsPrimaryAddress -like "True"} |select -ExpandProperty Smtpaddress 
            Secondary =  $_
        }
    }
}
```

This script (based off your script above) also reduces the number of server queries by 3 per user I think, so it should run a ton faster.

Comment: Sweet thats just what I was looking for!